# Flutter : geolocator dependecy issues - Build error

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, geocoding, fluttermap, geolocator

I'm getting the below error while building my flutter application itself.

```
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\geolocator_android-4.2.2\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\geolocator\location\FusedLocationClient.java:91: error: cannot find symbol
    LocationRequest.Builder builder = new LocationRequest.Builder(0);
                   ^
  symbol:   class Builder
  location: class LocationRequest
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\geolocator_android-4.2.2\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\geolocator\location\FusedLocationClient.java:91: error: cannot find symbol
    LocationRequest.Builder builder = new LocationRequest.Builder(0);
                                                         ^
  symbol:   class Builder
  location: class LocationRequest
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':geolocator_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
```

I'm using the below environment setup for in the pubspec.yaml

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.16.2 <3.0.0"
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.5
  get: ^4.6.5
  google_fonts: ^4.0.4
  lottie: ^1.4.2
  dob_input_field: ^2.0.0
  intl: ^0.17.0
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.2.3
  google_maps_flutter_web: ^0.4.0+5
  fluttertoast: ^8.2.1
  geocoding: ^2.0.5
  geocoder2: ^1.4.0
  flutter_polyline_points: ^1.0.0
  booking_calendar: ^1.1.9
  dropdown_button2: ^1.4.0
  intl_phone_field: ^3.1.0
  dropdown_textfield: ^1.0.1
  json_annotation: ^4.6.0
  dio: ^4.0.1
  retrofit: ^3.0.1+1
  retrofit_generator: ^4.0.1
  _fe_analyzer_shared: ^40.0.0
  logger: ^1.4.0
  table_calendar: ^3.0.8
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.17
  location: ^4.4.0
  image_picker: ^0.8.6
  flutter_google_places: ^0.3.0
  url_launcher: ^6.1.8
  carousel_slider: ^4.2.1
  barcode_scan2: ^4.2.4
  paytm_allinonesdk: ^1.1.7
  modal_bottom_sheet: ^2.0.1
  webview_flutter: ^3.0.4
  google_maps: ^6.2.0
  permission_handler: ^11.0.0
  flutter_dotenv: ^5.0.2
  geolocator: ^9.0.2
flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/
```

Could anyone suggest me the changes to resolve this issue?

I have modified the different version of geolocator and geocoding to verify but no changes.

I have cross-verified the flutter forum also, many developer is facing the similar problem but no solution has been found.

Comment: You should find an old version without the issue, keep downgrading till you can. Also run flutter clean every time (sometimes clearing cache takes time depending on system).

Also, have you tried latest version?

Comment: if you override geolocator_android with 4.2.0 then you won't face the build issue but the map won't load and no exception would throw. Starting from 4.2.1 geolocator android version, this error persists

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be solved when you run the "flutter clean" and then "flutter run" codes from the terminal.

Comment: Already tried and even cleared the pub cache also flutter pub cache repair but no change.